# Getting data from unsupported text file with VBA to Access table

Tags: ms-access, text, import, vba

I have an ale text file.
This file automatically created by a camera and it contains all the meta data of the recorded clips.

I would like to create a function that gets the ale file address (C:\test.ale) and adds all the rows (from row 11 and on, as you can see in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hoR7e.jpg)) of the columns "start","end","fps" & "gamma" from the test.ale file to "Camera meta data" table in my access database.

I have tried using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet and DoCmd.TransferText but this file type is not recognized by access.

I have added a [link to the ale file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzCkf0ywgE9XUFhXX2NYWjhzcms/view?usp=sharing) and a screenshot of the file as it opens by Excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create Saved Import: External Data -> Text File, when import ended, tick "Save Import" checkbox. After this you can run this saved import using `ImportExportSpecifications` object:

```
Dim ieImport As ImportExportSpecification
Set ieImport = CurrentProject.ImportExportSpecifications.Item("My Import Name")
ieImport.Execute
```

Import the data to temporary table and delete unnecessary rows with service data or use this service data if needed.

Comment: I cant do that because ale is an unrecognized text file

Comment: @mzag: rename the file to `A001R6Y6_AVID.tab`, because the values are Tab separated. The usual extension for this was `.tsv`, but Access wants `.tab` :shrug: